# How do I solve the Robyn Error: Input 'factor_vars' must be any from 'context_vars' inputs

Tags: python

```
Error in check_factorvars(dt_input, factor_vars, context_vars) : 
  Input 'factor_vars' must be any from 'context_vars' inputs
```

```
 context_vars = c(
    "A",
    "B",
    "C")

factor_vars = c("event", "defects", "fraud", "outage")
```

this is part of the MMM code and used to run before and now there is an error. There are no null values in dataset

Comment: it seems that `check_factorvars` has some validation checks, that require `factor_vars` to be a subset of `context_vars` - It's likely this function code what changed.

Comment: Thank you - this is helpful. Should I include the variables in both context and factor